# IntelliJ JavaFX native .deb bundle "is of bad quality" Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, javafx, deb

I have developed a Javafx application under IntelliJ IDEA. As a JavaFX project, I am given the option to build a native bundle alongside the .jar and .jnlp file. I choose to export a .deb native. I build and export the project on IntelliJ running on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. The .deb file is created. However, when I use Ubuntu Software Center to install the program, it prompts me with "The package is of bad quality"

This is the full error (save some repetitive lines):

```
Lintian check results for /home/guyfleeman/Dropbox/PROGRAMMING/Java/VaSOLSim/out/artifacts/VSS_TeacherClient/bundles/VSS-TeacherClient-1.0.deb:
E: VSS-TeacherClient: control-file-has-bad-permissions postinst 0775 != 0755
E: VSS-TeacherClient: control-file-has-bad-owner postinst guyfleeman/guyfleeman != root/root
E: VSS-TeacherClient: control-file-has-bad-permissions postrm 0775 != 0755
E: VSS-TeacherClient: control-file-has-bad-owner postrm guyfleeman/guyfleeman != root/root
E: VSS-TeacherClient: bad-package-name
E: VSS-TeacherClient: package-not-lowercase
E: VSS-TeacherClient: maintainer-address-missing Freeware - William Stuckey
E: VSS-TeacherClient: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/ 1000/1000
E: VSS-TeacherClient: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/VSS-TeacherClient/ 1000/1000
E: VSS-TeacherClient: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/VSS-TeacherClient/VSS-TeacherClient 1000/1000
E: VSS-TeacherClient: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/VSS-TeacherClient/VSS-TeacherClient.desktop 1000/1000
E: VSS-TeacherClient: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/VSS-TeacherClient/VSS-TeacherClient.png 1000/1000
E: VSS-TeacherClient: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/VSS-TeacherClient/app/ 1000/1000
E: VSS-TeacherClient: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/VSS-TeacherClient/app/VSS-TeacherClient.jar 1000/1000
...
```

I have the choice to ignore these errors and install anyway. If I ignore the error, the program installs and runs fine.

Does anyone know how to properly export the .deb file under IntelliJ? Also, I figured this question would be more at home here rather than at superuser, but I'll move it upon request.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: It might be an error with the [Installed size](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Installed-Size). In Netbeans you have to go at `/nbproject/configurations.xml` and add a line after `<packInfoList>` such as `<packInfoListElem name="Installed-Size" value="528" mandatory="true"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in Java 7 when packaging Debian packages, which would lead to the "The package is of bad quality" warning.

- [RT-27989
  Linux DEB installer does not specify Installed-Size](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27989)
- [RT-33784
  [Packager] Disturbing Alert Dialog at installation of Linux DEB package](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33784)

(account needed to view the bug tracker info, but anybody can sign up for an account).

The issue was fixed for Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

When I got a similar error, I ran the jfx:native goal as root, and it got rid of all those file-owner and permissions warnings.  The owners of the various files in the package need to belong to users with ID's in a certain range, of which root is included.